# View does not render dictionary correctly

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a simple Django REST Framework view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def foo(request):
    response = { 'message': 'foo'}
    return Response(response)
```

When I access the endpoint from Chrome, I only see the key of the dictionary, not the value:

```
message
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a JsonResponse:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

@api_view(['GET'])
def foo(request):
    response = {'message': 'foo'}
    return JsonResponse(response)
```